# Density function of binary expansions and convergence in distribution.

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory

I am trying to prove the next:

Let $x \in (0,1)$ have a binary expansion $$x = \displaystyle\sum_{n = 1}^{\infty}\frac{d_n}{2^n}.$$ Set 
$$f_{n}(x) = \left\{ \begin{array}{lcc}
             2 &   if  & d_n = 0 
             \\ 1 &  if  & d_n = 1
             \end{array}
   \right.$$

Then $\int_{0}^{1}f_n(x)dx = 1$ so that $f_n$ is a density. The sequence $f_n$ only converges on a set of Lebesgue measure 0. If $X_n$ is a random variable with density $f_n$ then $X_n\Rightarrow U,$ where $U$ is $U(0,1).$

I am not sure about to prove this. I don't think that $f_n$ be a density function; my feeling is such integral has value 1 because the set of points in which a binary expansion has $d_n \in {0, 1}$ has Lebesgue measure positive such that evaluating the integral gives that value, but I don't reach a result of this kind.

For the second part I think is enough to prove that the set of binary expansion with a constant tails of $d_n = 0$ 0r $d_n = 1$ is Lebesgue zero.

Last part I do not see an approachable way.

Any kind of help is thanked in advanced.

Comment: Why do you think $\int f_n = 1$?  Shouldn't it be $(1+2)/2$ instead?

Comment: It is an exercise of the book "A Probability Path," ex. 8.28. It is established in that form.

Comment: I bet there is a typo in that exercise, and $f_n(x)=0$ if $d_n=1$ is what's meant.